# Why i've got "550 Cannot establish SSL session" error when i sending mail from codeIgniter framework with poste.io server mail?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, docker, smtp

I've got some problems to sending mail from my web server.

I've got an poste.io container from DockerHub and an apache/php container with codeIgniter php framework load on it. this one sending mail to WAN IP adress on smtp_port 465 :

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => '<my-server-ip>',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'noreply@<domain.org>',
    'smtp_pass' => '<noreply-password>',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
```

and return :

> hello: 550 Cannot establish SSL session
>   The following SMTP error was encountered: 550 Cannot establish SSL session
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

I tried with port 25 and he return :

> Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 500 Unrecognized command 
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Poste.io is a webmail client and server based on docker container with port 465, 443, 110, 143, 587, 993, 995 are opened and container surely running. Poste.io generate a certificat when container start. I tried to re-generate him manually but it's also doesn't work...

Do you know what i've got to do for sending mail from codeIgniter throw my poste.io mail server container ?

Thanks for reply !

Comment: please, nobody know ?